# Move solution from one VS Online TFS project to another

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

So I made a mistake when setting up a project within Visual Studio Online (VSO) and TFS. I chose the SCRUM option rather than Agile option and now I need to move my code to a new project I setup in VSO that makes use of Agile.

Since my Visual Studio solution and all its files are already controlled by one VSO/TFS project is it possible to move them to a different project? I tried to change the existing project from SCRUM to Agile but evidently once it is set in the project there is not going back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you can't change the process template for an existing project.
However, moving the code with a simple snapshot mode is very easy.

You need to make sure that you have the latest version of the code locally on your pc in a workspace mapped to your Scrum project.

You then map the source folder of your Agile project to a different folder on your pc, copy the code from the Scrum workspace to the Agile workspace and use the Source Control Explorer to add the code to your new project.

This way however you won't copy any of the history to your new project. If you wan't to establish history between your two team projects, you can branch the code from TP1 to TP2. In your history you will see the point where you branched and you can look at the history before that moment.

Answer (score 5):

Here are detailed steps that I followed to accomplish the task:

1. Create new project in VSTS (renamed from VSO). In Visual Studio "Get Latest Version" to create the folder on the local computer.
2. In Visual Studio "Get Latest Version" of project which needs to be moved.
3. Copy it to new project folder (using Windows Explorer)
4. Open the solution and Remove Source Control binding (File -> Source Control -> Advanced and unbind everything).
5. Close VS and delete the source control files (*.vssscc).
6. Delete the Source Control Project files as well (*.vspscc)

   ***(not a deal breaker but it prevents an error)***
7. Open the solution and add it to Source Control
8. Check it in.
9. Using Source Control Explorer in VS, right click the project, Branching and Merging -> Merge, the old project with the new one (choose options appropriate for you in the wizard).
10. Check it in.

In VSTS under the history of the code files, there should now be a "Show merge history" link where you can see the previous history of the files.